# How to update from libjpeg.so.8 to libjpeg.so.9 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04, libpng, libjpeg

Attempting to build an application based on OpenCV, I see two lines warning me of missing libraries for `libjpeg` and `libpng`. Here is an extract of the console output, which then goes on with a number of similar Qt-related issues.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjpeg.so.9, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpng16.so.16, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `QGraphicsView::viewportEvent(QEvent*)@Qt_5'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `QAbstractSlider::value() const@Qt_5'
```

Researching a bit around, I found out how to show which libraries and versions I have installed on my system using `ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg` and `ldconfig -p | grep libpng`. They gave me the following:

```
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

and

```
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so
```

I clearly see I have an issue. The libraries installed on my computer are older than those required by OpenCV. However, I tried `sudo apt install libjpeg-dev`, and to `sudo apt update` but I haven't found the newer version being available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to install `libjpeg9` on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt install libjpeg9-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

For installing libjpeg9 Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg9-dev
```

Comment: The only difference between this answer and the one I posted months ago is that you are using `apt` in an outdated way. In what precisely is this answer enriching?